# bash: nested double quote and dollar sign

Tags: bash, syntax, syntax-highlighting

```
sh -c "$(curl -Ls "https://my-domain.com/a.sh?v=$(date +%s)")"
```

I want to exec a remote sh file and make sure no cache is using.

I know the command above can work, but it is not friendly with syntax highlighting when I put it on a markdown document.

what's the correct way to write nested double quotes and $ sign command ?

Comment: That's a problem with the syntax highlighter, not your code. It stems from the fact that most syntax highlighters use regular expressions for speed and simplicity, and the new quoting context established by a command substitution is non-regular.

Comment: For this case, you could just avoid nesting and do `curl -Ls ... | sh`

Comment: One of the  reasons to prefer `$(…)` over backticks is the fact that it can be nested (as in your example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the correct way. If the syntax highlighter doesn't highlight it properly (e.g. on Stack Exchange, lol), that's the syntax highlighter's fault. [chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner) explains [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57063447/bash-nested-double-quote-and-dollar-sign#comment100652175_57063447):

> That's a problem with the syntax highlighter, not your code. It stems from the fact that most syntax highlighters use regular expressions for speed and simplicity, and the new quoting context established by a command substitution is non-regular.

However, as [William Pursell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/140750/william-pursell) said [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57063447/bash-nested-double-quote-and-dollar-sign/57063661#comment100652185_57063447),

> For this case, you could just avoid nesting and do `curl -Ls ... | sh`

i.e.

```
curl -Ls "https://my-domain.com/a.sh?v=$(date +%s)" | sh
```

**Related**

- [l0b0's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/118438/117037) on [Quoting within $(command substitution) in Bash - Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/118433/117037)